# Expected value of a point/dot to be near the closest side of a square surface?

Tags: probability

If we choose a random point inside a square of side length 1, what is the probability for the point is nearest a chosen side of the square?

I would say that the answer is 1/4 since there are 4 sides but I don't think that's right.

Can anyone give a formula proof to this problem?

Picture demonstration:

[image: The Square]

Comment: What do you mean "near the closest side of a square surface"? Do you mean if you choose a point uniformly in a square, what is the probability it is closest to a given side?

Comment: Heading says *probability*, body says *expected value*.

Comment: @Batman yes that' s correct look at the picture in the link

Comment: @trueblueanil I've changed the heading, sorry for that.

Comment: Seems like you actually wanted probability.

Comment: I've trouble with translating from one language to another... I wish I would had my courses in english...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you draw the two diagonals of the square (which divides the square into 4 triangles), note that each triangle contains precisely the points closest to the side of the square it contains (*). Each triangle has $\frac{1}{4}$ of the area of the square by symmetry.

Thus, the probability of a uniformly randomly chosen point in the square to be closest to a given side is $\frac{1}{4}$.

(*) This is easy to see. The points above one diagonal are clearly closer to two sides than the other two sides. Combine this observation with the other diagonal to see the diagonals partition the square by which side the points are closest to.

Comment: I' was just starting to do this xd. Tnx!